# Python - using tks.color_tints_and_shades

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to Python and am looking to use the tkStuff package to generate Colour Tints. Information is available here: http://pythonhosted.org/tks/colors.html

I have successfully installed and imported ColorTint (from tks.color_tints_and_shades import ColorTint) however I have not been able to get it working.

As a newbie I am struggling to get a working script. Ideally I would like the user to input RGB values and have the resulting tints returned. An alternative (and probably more complex) would be to read a file of RGB values and write a file of original colour followed by the tints.

All help much appreciated!

Thanks,
A

edit:

I have tried this so far -

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk

from tks.color_tints_and_shades import ColorTint
from tks.color_var import ColorVar

colour = (100,150, 200)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Colour Tint')
    entry = ColorTint(root, colour, count=5, percent=(1,5) )
    entry.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.mainloop()
```

I have started (or attempted to start) with a hard-coded RGB value initially.

Comment: Cool. Does it work, if not what is the error message, or what is it doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't work. I get the following error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alan\Dropbox\Python\tks_ColorTint.py", line 14, in <module>
    entry = ColorTint(root, colour, count=5, percent=(1,5) )
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\tks\color_tints_and_shades.py", line 139, in __init__
    func=rgb_tints)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\tks\color_tints_and_shades.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.color_var.trace_variable('w', self._color_var_changed)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'trace_variable'

Comment: This is the problematic line:     entry = ColorTint(root, colour, count=5, percent=(1,5) ). What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You've set the variable `colour` as a tuple:

```
colour = (100, 150, 200)
```

But according to http://pythonhosted.org/tks/colors.html#tks.color_tints_and_shades.ColorTint since you are passing it as the second parameter to `ColorTint`, it should be of type `tks.color_var.ColorVar`.